# Dart: dynamic redirection without reload

Tags: dart, single-page-application, dart-html

Please note I'm not interested in a Polymer-, Angular- or route-based solution here. I'm trying to learn "pure" Dart here, and while I'll likely switch to using one of those frameworks down the road, I need to have a good understanding of the fundamentals first.

In Dart, is it possible to download a whole bunch of HTML "snippets" (see below) all at once (at app startup), and then load them into the browser (either the entire window or just inside a particular `<div>` element, etc.) dynamically?

For instance, my HTML file might have a `<div>` element:

```html
<body>
    <!-- lots of HTML -->

    <div id="container"></div>

    <!-- more HTML -->
</body>
```

And I would like to download two "snippets" (DOM subtrees, HTML templates) of HTML, and dynamically load either one of them into the `container` div tag. Perhaps one of the snippets looks like this:

```html
<h1>I'm Snippet #1!!!</h1>
<input type="button" name="redPillButton" value="Red Pill!" />
```

And another snippet my look like:

```html
<h1>I'm Snippet #2!!!</h1>
<input type="button" name="bluePillButton" value="Blue Pill!" />
```

Can the two snippets be inside their own HTML file, or do I **have** to put them inside one big file and extract out the "snippet" that I want to load? Either way, how do I accomplish this in a Dart web app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep each parts in their own file and load them like that :

```dart
HttpRequest.getString("part.html").then((html) {
  querySelector('#container').innerHtml = html;
});
```